# What's a way that my command could take 2 strings

Tags: c#, .net, discord.net

I am setting up a discord bot for encrypting data. I want the user to be able to type something such as:

```
e.encrypt "data to be encrypted" "their hash of choice"
```

I've tried to split the string from [Remainder] but I can't figure out what to do next. It also won't allow them to freely type.

```
[Command("encrypt")]
public async Task encrypt([Remainder] string Idata)
{
    var des = new Methods.DES();

    des.input = Idata;
    des.hash = "hello";

    des.Encryption();

    await Context.User.SendMessageAsync(des.encryption);

}
```

If they type something such as

```
e.encrypt "Hello" "hashkey"
```

then I want the bot to understand that the content between the first `""` is the data and the content between the next `""` is the hash.

Comment: I would consider a regular expression, check [RegEx reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.7.2) That way you could check both if the data is in the correct sintax and get the desired parts.

Comment: Offtopic/unrelated note: Do never user DES, use a robust encryption instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect the command to be executed like `e.encrypt "Hello" "hashkey"` then simply use

```cs
[Command("encrypt")]
public async Task encrypt(string data, string hash)
{
    //your code here
}
```

The remainder attribute is only used if you want the user to enter a multi-part string without the use of quotation marks.

Comment: Thank you this is EXACTLY what I was trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Is it of much importance to you to have certain punctuation, like a : or a ~ for example? Because if not, I would suggest you don't worry about the quotes and have something along the lines of "e.encrypt Hello:Hashkey" where a certain character splits the two. That way, you can easily split the message into the two strings with `String[] data = Idata.split(":")` (or whatever character you choose) and use a method to remove the e.encrypt. You could also use this strategy to implement it with the quotes, but it will be a little bit longer